# Right mouse click not working on Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, 17.10

After upgrading from Kubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 I cannot right mouse click anymore on my touchpad (Lenovo T460s). Left mouse click still works.

I have reviewed the touchpad/mouse settings, but nothing seems to relevant.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Or how to debug at least?

Comment: It still happens from time to time that the right mouse button stops working. `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprode psmouse` makes it functional again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my lenovo ideapad 320e. Previously, editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptic.conf worked but the file is missing here altogether in ubuntu 17.10.

**Alternate solution:**

*Simulate a right mouse click*.

Go to Universal Access in Settings > Go to Click assist > Switch on Simulated Secondary Click > Adjust the primary click duration to trigger right click and you're set.

Hope, it helps for the time being.

EDIT:
BTW Did you try double finger right click?
Just tap on trackpad using two fingers.

Comment: so, strangely, right mouse click started working by itself after suspend...